# メインのナビゲーションメニューに「未解決」タブを追加したいですか？

Tags: 討議, 完了

翻訳をしてくれた[@nekketsuuu](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu)に感謝します。

---

Stack Exchangeの多くのサイトには「未解決 (Unanswered)」というタブがメインのナビゲーションメニューにあります。たとえば下の画像は[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)のものです。

[image]

見たところ、日本語版スタック・オーバーフローにはこのタブがありません。同僚と話してみたのですが、これを有効にすることに特段反対意見が出ませんでした。

日本語版スタック・オーバーフローのメインのナビゲーションメニューに、未解決の質問へのリンクを設置したいと思いますか？　なにか反対意見はありますでしょうか？

---

未解決の質問とは、承認された回答や+1投票された回答が投稿されていない質問のことです。

Comment: Currently we can access to it by 質問 -> 未解決: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Unanswered

Comment: 現状でもトップページで一番下までスクロールすると [未解決の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/unanswered) としてリンクがあります。

Answer (score 10):

特に反対意見を思いつきません。回答活動をより活発にするためにも、追加して良いと思います

Answer (score 5):

「タブの追加」自体には賛成ですが、質問一覧の並び替え順は検討の余地があるかもしれません。

デフォルトでは恐らく質問への票数を元に並び替えされるので、(4,5年前の)古い質問が多く表示されている印象です。古い質問に回答しても「当時とは状況が変わっている」「質問者が既にサイトを離れている」などの理由で、(必須じゃないけど)承認されない、第三者も回答の評価を付けづらかったりでCommunityユーザーが定期的に上げるだけになったりしないかなぁとも思います。

カスタマイズが可能であるなら、直近の質問を優先した方が幸せになれるかもしれません。

Comment: 未解決タブってむしろそういう古い質問にも目を向けるためのものだと思っていました。票数順って、新旧関わらず価値のある質問の順番という意味ですよね。票数順で問題があるなら、むしろ最近の質問に票が集まっていないことを問題視すべきなのかもしれません。（それが解決しづらいので順番の方を見直すべき、という流れになるのかもしれませんが……）